# Mearging measurements in InfluxDB - heapster

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb

Im exploring kubernetes and came across its monitoring tool heapster which uses influxDB

is there a way to create a custom influxDB which has the values of only those certain measurements which I need?

For eg. I want to track the cpu usage, memory usage and network bandwidth. But heapsters schema has these 3 in 3 separate measurements.